# iOS font with monospace digits 0...9?

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, ios, monospace

This is for an app displaying rows of numbers that change dynamically. A monospace font would be ideal to prevent distracting alignment jumps as digits change.

I really only care about digits, so does anyone know of built-in iOS fonts (other than Courier) that are monospace as far as the characters 0 to 9 are concerned?

Comment: Why not simply embed a monospace font?

Comment: I haven't considered that, font licensing issues could be a concern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several iOS built-in fonts have monospaced digit characters, including the system default Helvetica Neue, <s>Helvetica</s>, Verdana, American Typewriter, Chalkboard SE, Copperplate, Gill Sans, Marker Felt, Trebuchet MS (and probably more)

Comment: Thanks! I tried Helvetica (on a Mac) and the digits are not monospace. But you're right about Helvetica Neue and Verdana.

Comment: Thank you for the correction! I found a nice site for previewing all iOS fonts at once: http://iosfonts.com

Comment: I can't believe I never knew half of these fonts had monospaced numerals. I feel a bit stupid.

Answer (score 1):

Verdana is the best and is free. Numbers are clear and line up perfectly. Everything will be neetly aligned. There are others but I prefer Verdana.

Comment: Well, verdana has been mentioned in the acepted answer. I see no addidional information here. One way to make it an good answer would be to add a screenshot with numbers and compare verdana with other fonts you didn't name ...

Comment: Also I _hate_ Verdana, but that's just opinion.

Comment: I agree that Verdana is the best font for numbers in iOS. 2:1.

Answer (score 1):

Helvetica has a variant with monospaced digits. Use

```css
.your_class {
   font-variant-numeric: tabular-nums
}
```

in CSS or [this](https://gist.github.com/liorazi/94e85f36e97908716e48f0ebb0ac753a#file-font-monospaceddigits-swift) in Swift.